# Программа, которая получает через командную строку размер массива. Если количество параметров меньше требуемого, используется значения по умолчанию

Tags: java

```
int leng = 5;
leng = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int[] a;
a = new int[leng];
```

Программа, которая  принимает размер массива через командную строку представлена выше. Но как реализовать следующую ситуацию: если параметр не был передан,программа не выдает ошибку(как это обычно бывает), а использует значение по умолчанию(в нашем случае 5).

Comment: Вам надо проверить, что аргумент, переданный в программу, может быть преобразован в число.

Comment: каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Используйте условный оператор с проверкой того, что количество параметров отлично от нуля. Условные опраторы проходили?

Answer (score 1):

```
int leng = 5;
if (args.length > 0) {
    leng = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // полагаем, что args[0] содержит целое число
}
int[] a;
a = new int[leng];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
все что связано с попыткой получить параметр
} catch (Exception e) {
// ничего не делать
}
```

Оберните попытку получения параметра в `try`  `catch` и выловите все возможные исключения.  Программа или получит корректный  параметр или останется со значением по умолчанию.

Comment: НИКОГДА!!!!!!! не оставляйте `catch` пустым!!! Слышите??? НИ-КОГ-ДА!! И потом - вопрос был не в корректности параметра, а в его наличии-отсутствии.

Comment: А какое поведение тут правильное в случае исключения? Вывести в консоль, выйти по ошибке, отправить sms CEO? Если параметр отсутствует это будет тоже исключение.

Comment: Если уж надо проверять целое число или нет, то ловить надо `NFE`, а наличие-отсутствие параметра вообще - проверкой `if`

Comment: Почему вы именно так считаете?

Comment: В продакшине пустые `catch` - плохой тон. Даже если переменную назвать `ignored`. Плохой тон также ловить все возможные исключения и реагировать на них одинаково (за редкими исключениями)